Revit API Column Axis Auto Dimension

I want to measure the axis and column I selected in Revit using Visual Studio C#, as shown in the picture. Is there a way to automatically create these measurements from the centers of the axes?
I did research on the internet. I only came across examples that give one measurement. It is said that it is impossible to measure the arc axis. is this true? can you please help me on this.
Good work everyone
I want to measure the axle and column automatically
